# How do I access ETW Traces on SQL Server for linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, extended-events

I have SQL Server running in a docker image. I have an extended event session running on it. I can connect to it fine and view live data with SSMS. I can use T-SQL to view the histogram target. If this was a windows box, I could use logman.exe to view and manage the event trace session. How do I do it in SQL Server for Linux?

I am absolutely sure that the ETW is getting created.

```
SELECT
    xes.name AS [Session Name],
    CAST(xest.target_data AS xml) [Histogram XML],
    xest.target_name
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets xest  
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions xes ON xes.address = xest.event_session_address  
    WHERE xest.target_name = 'etw_classic_sync_target';
```

`<ETWTarget truncated="0">
  <DefaultETWSession>
    <Name>XE_DEFAULT_ETW_SESSION</Name>
    <Path>C:\Users\Client\Temp\XEEtw.etl</Path>
    <BufferSizeKb>128</BufferSizeKb>
    <FileSizeMb>20</FileSizeMb>
  </DefaultETWSession>
  <DefaultXESession>
    <Name>XE_DEFAULT_ETW_SESSION</Name>
  </DefaultXESession>
</ETWTarget>`

However, if I execute `find / -iname XEEtw.etl` inside bash on the docker container I get no results. I know that SQL Server on Linux is running its own internal copy of Windows NT. I just don't know if that ETW is exposed.

Comment: why don't you choose a file or ring buffer target and read from there? There is no ETW on Linux

Comment: @rudibruchez Well if I could avoid writing XPath to get tabular output it would be nice. I guess I could learn PowerBI or PowerQuery to get that though.

Comment: You can use SSMS to show the tabular result of a file target

Answer (score 1):

> How do I access ETW Traces on SQL Server for linux?

Unfortunately, ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) is not available on Linux.  It is a Windows-only function.  So for the time being you are stuck with the SQL and filesystem options for view the EE data.

The .NET Core team chose [LTTng](https://lttng.org/) for trace support when .NET apps are running on Linux.  You could explore that as an option for correlating OS events with those recorded by SQL Server.

---

After your update (super interesting that ETW events might be firing in Drawbridge), I see that the .etl file is getting created on a file path that probably doesn't exist on your Linux-based Docker container.  You should try setting a known-good file path when you create the XE session:

```
ADD TARGET package0.etw_classic_sync_target   
    (SET default_etw_session_logfile_path = N'/temp/sqletw.etl' )
```